# Sharepoint via web service : checking if item exists in list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-services

Because Microsoft did not include a way to have unique constraints in sharepoint, this has to be done manually.

I am inserting items into a sharepoint list via a web service method.

How can I check if an existing list item already exists with the same field ID value?

I've learnt I should be using wsLists.getListitems web service method, but its not exactly "user friendly". MSDN documentation is again not really great at explaining what should be an easy thing to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private bool itemDoesntExist()
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<Document><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">" + this.ID  + "</Value></Contains></Where></Query><ViewFields /><QueryOptions /></Document>");
    XmlNode listQuery = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Query");
    XmlNode listViewFields = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ViewFields");
    XmlNode listQueryOptions = doc.SelectSingleNode("//QueryOptions");
    XmlNode items = this.wsLists.GetListItems(this.ListName , string.Empty, listQuery, listViewFields, string.Empty, listQueryOptions, null);
    if (items.ChildNodes[1].Attributes["ItemCount"].Value == "0")
    {
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use non-negative method names, like ItemExist(). It's far more easy to read.

Comment: I agree with Magnus on the naming issue, but I like the succinctness of your solution using XML to get the information you need.  One more vote and you can get the badge for answering your own question with 3+ votes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a procedure I wrote 2 years ago that pulls the ID of a document with a given filename... I think you could easily revise it to return true/false if a given ID exists in a list.

```
protected string GetDocumentID(Lists.Lists ls, string ListGUID, string FileName)
{
    string strDocumentID = "-1";

    string strViewGUID = "";
    string strRowLimit = "50000";

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode query = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
    XmlNode viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
    XmlNode queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

    query.InnerXml = "";
    viewFields.InnerXml = "";
    queryOptions.InnerXml = "<IncludeAttachmentUrls>TRUE</IncludeAttachmentUrls>";

    System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems = ls.GetListItems(ListGUID, strViewGUID, query, viewFields, strRowLimit, queryOptions, null);

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(nodeListItems.InnerXml);
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("rs", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset");

    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/rs:data/z:row", nsmgr))
    {
        if (node.Attributes["ows_LinkFilename"].Value == FileName)
        {
            strDocumentID = node.Attributes["ows_ID"].Value;
            break;
        }
    }

    return strDocumentID;
}
```

Here's the code that calls it...

```
Lists.Lists ls = new Lists.Lists();
ls.PreAuthenticate = true;
ls.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
ls.Url = SharePointSiteURL + @"/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

string DocID = GetDocumentID(ls, ListGUID, FileName);
```

Comment: +1 for effort of a usable code block. I got it working will post another easier way

Comment: I figured there was a way to be cleaner with XML but the project was rushed beyond reason and it was a one-time deal (copy data from non-SharePoint repository to SharePoint) - this was a "make it work" effort. :)